# If neither of $f: A \to B$ or $g:B \to C$ is one-to-one can $ g \circ f$ be one-to-one?

Tags: functions

The title says it all - but to reiterate:

If neither of $f: A \to B$  or $g:B \to C$ is one-to-one can $ g \circ f$ be one-to-one?

I think not. Anyone have a good proof for this? This is simply curiosity - we recently reviewed the composition of one-to-one and onto functions.

thanks.

Comment: Convention states that the composite map $A \to C$ be denoted $g\circ f$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not one-to-one, then $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ for some elements $a_1,a_2\in A$ with $a_1\neq a_2$. Let $b=f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. Then $g\circ f(a_1) = g(b) = g\circ f(a_2)$, so $g\circ f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Technically you've exchanged the roles of $f$ and $g$ relative to the OP.

Comment: But only half the time.

Comment: @Ian yeah, I figured that was the order that was meant in the OP. As it is written (and with the usual way of writing function composition), $f\circ g$ is not defined.

Comment: @HowDoIMath You're right!

Comment: For completeness I should mention that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are distinct.

Comment: @drhab oh right, I've included it in my post.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem** *If $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ and $g\circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.*

*Proof.* Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x,y\in A$; then $g\circ f(x)=g\circ f(y)$, so…

---

**Further exercise** Show that if $g\circ f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is not one-one that means that there is atleast one pair of $x_1,x_2 \in A$ ($x_1\ne x_2$) such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

$g\circ f(x_1)=g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))=g\circ f(x_2)$

Since $g\circ f(x_1)=g\circ f(x_2)$ does not imply that $x_1=x_2$

Therefore $g\circ f$ is not one-one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $g\circ f$ is one-to-one.

If $f(a)=f(b)$ then $g\circ f(a)=g(f(a))=g(f(b))=g\circ f(b)$ so we are allowed to conclude that $a=b$.

Proved is now: $$g\circ f\text{ is one-to-one}\implies f\text{ is one-to-one}$$
Of course this is the same as:
$$f\text{ is not one-to-one}\implies g\circ f\text{ is not one-to-one}$$